# Checkbox OnChecked ChangeListener in Codename one

Tags: ios, codenameone

Am creating Check Box dynamically, is there any way to find whether the Checkbox is checked or not in inside the chkBox.addActionListener() in Codename One.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like:

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)ev.getSource();
```